# AngularJS ui.router, change to parent from child state, no reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

There are similar questions, but none about this specific case.

I have a navbar where the user can go to states `posts` and `notifications`. In the posts-state it's possible to click on a post and go to `posts.details`. Same in notifications-state.

`posts` and `posts.detail` share the controller and template.

What works: `navbar->posts`, then click on a post, user lands in `posts.details`, again `navbar->posts`, user sees last x posts.

Doesn't work: `navbar->notifications`, click on a notification (from a post), user lands in `posts.detail`. So far ok. Now click on `navbar->posts`, the controller won't reload.

Here some code snippets:

route.js

```
   .state('posts', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'client/Posts/posts.ng.html',
      controller: 'PostsCtrl',
      resolve: {
        'subscribtion': ['speakLocalData', function(speakLocalData) {
          return speakLocalData.subscribeAll();
        }]
      }
    })
  .state('posts.detail', {
      url: 'posts/:id',
      templateUrl: 'client/Posts/posts.ng.html',
      controller: 'PostsCtrl',
      resolve: {
        'currentUser': ['$meteor', function($meteor) {
          return $meteor.requireUser();
        }]
      }
    })
```

navbar.ng.html

```
<li ui-sref-active="active">
    <a ui-sref="posts">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
    </a>
  </li>

    <li ui-sref-active="active" ng-show="$root.currentUser">
        <div class="noti_bubble" ng-show="notiCounter>0">{{ notiCounter }}</div>
        <a ui-sref="notifications">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></span>
      </a>
  </li>
```

There is a live version [here](http://speaklocal.meteor.com/). Login with username: `demo`, password: `demo123`.

Github repository of source code: [here](https://github.com/fdelia/speaklocal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref) you can use the `ui-sref-opts` directive to reload the controller when changing state:

```
<a ui-sref="notifications" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}">...</a>
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you! I still don't understand why it reloads in one case and not in the other case, but that's of no concern.